# Google Cloud Dataproc cluster creation failure due to Cloud SQL proxy initialization error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a `Dataproc` cluster from a `Cloud Composer` `DAG` using the `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` of `Airflow`. I need to access `Cloud SQL` from my `Dataproc` cluster hence need to install the `Cloud SQL proxy` on the cluster as well. I am providing the initialization action for `Cloud SQL Proxy` as per [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy#using-this-initialization-action) in my cluster config for the `Airflow` operator as below:

```
"initialization_actions": [
        {
           "executable_file" : "gs://<<some_gcs_bucket>>/cloud-sql-proxy.sh"
        }
    ],

"gce_cluster_config": {
        "service_account_scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin"],
        "metadata" : {
             "enable-cloud-sql-hive-metastore" : "false",
             "additional-cloud-sql-instances" : "<<PROJECT_ID>>:<<REGION>>:<<INSTANCE_NAME>>"
        }
    }
```

The cluster creation fails with below message:

> google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Initialization action
> failed. Failed action 'gs://<<some_gcs_bucket>>/cloud-sql-proxy.sh',
> see output in:
> gs://<<some_gcs_bucket>>/dataproc-initialization-script-0_output

I might be putting the parameters in the cluster config wrongly like the metadata arguments required by the initialization script, if anybody has implemented this use-case previously then would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: What's the error message in gs://<<some_gcs_bucket>>/dataproc-initialization-script-0_output?

Comment: Below is the message in  dataproc-initialization-script-0_output:

2022-07-09 10:25:38 URL:https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 [16903544/16903544] -> "cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64" [1]
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cloud-sql-proxy.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-sql-proxy.service.
Cloud SQL Proxy installation succeeded
Logs can be found in /var/log/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.log
/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0: line 311: /etc/mysql/conf.d/cloud-sql-proxy.cnf: No such file or directory

Comment: Which image version are you using?

Comment: We are using 1.5.53-centos8 to create this cluster.

Comment: The issue might be specific to CentOS. Can you try Debian/Ubuntu? If that's confirmed, I'll investigate and fix it.

Comment: I tried with 1.5.71-debian10 and 1.5.71-ubuntu18 and the cluster was successfully created with successful installation of cloud sql proxy. This seems to be an issue specific to centOS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was specific to CentOS and Rocky. The support for CentOS and Rocky has been added in this [PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/pull/1006). To use it, you can copy the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/master/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh) from Github and upload it to your own GCS bucket.